# triggers and how to use them in phpmyadmin tool

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I just downloaded WAMP server to use on a small college project that accompanies a basic SQL course.When ever i open the the mysql console window in WAMP i am asked for a password but since there is no password i don't key it in and continue. I created a few tables and a few triggers using the phpmyadmin tool. The insert statements work fine when there are no triggers but give me an error saying "mysql.proc doesn't exist" if i try to insert with triggers enabled. Can someone help me out with this . I really don't understand how to grant privileges and stuff and how to set the password . ( i just bought a pc 4 days ago) . Can someone please help me out ?(detailed noob steps please?)

Comment: This isn't a training site. Show what you've tied so far (queries, etc...) and we can help fix it, but we're not going to be your school or teacher.

Comment: ok i'm sorry. ok basically every table has 4 attributes. name ,id ,runs and wickets. there are 4 tables. league1,league2,leagu3,league4 with league4 having only elite players. when a player does well in a lower league he is promoted to a higher league. i inserted rows into each table normally and it worked perfectly fine when the promotion triggers were not enabled. but when i did enable the triggers i got an error message say "mysql_proc doesn't exist" . i am not sure what this means. or how to fix it.

Comment: @SrinivasSuresh Have you created any stored procedures?

Comment: MySQL was upgraded but the `mysql_upgrade` script/program wasn't run to update the tables. So there were tables that had incompatibilities with the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring [this](http://mysql-tools.com/articles/mysql/48-table-mysqlproc-doesnt-exist.html) link and [this](http://rackerhacker.com/2007/11/29/table-mysqlproc-doesnt-exist/) link, itseems you are running into some version problems with mysql. Try to get the latest WAMP setup.

Comment: Thank you ! turns out it was a problem with the computer. Still haven't figured what though. I downloaded the latest version of WAMP on a different computer and it worked.